# datalab folder is missing from root in google colab

Tags: python, machine-learning, directory, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to run some machine learning in Google Colab.

However, there is one line that says

```
%cd ~/datalab
```

But it can't find the 'datalab' folder.

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/datalab'
```

I checked if it's there in content and root using !ls and os.listdir but there's nothing.

I also tried mounting my content folder but it doesn't fix the datalab problem.

Why is 'datalab' missing?

How can I fix it?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Where did you find your code ? Do you have a datalab folder somewhere ? there is no datalab folder by default on colab I think. May be your code come from a notebook used in datalab (datalab is the paying cloud service from google for machine learning) and not in google colab

Answer (score 0):

The error names the problem. You'll want to create the directory before attempting to switch to it using a command like:

```
!mkdir -p /root/datalab
```